# Paypal IPN customer address not needed

Tags: paypal-ipn

I wrote a paypal IPN procedure that works fine and I'm continuing to test that via sandbox.

Everytime I simulate the payment I see that the custom address is displayed but I don't need it because I want to sell a web service and I want more privacy for my customers.

How can I hide the shipping address from the payment page of paypal? (even if it's possible...)

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question, the solution is in this link:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/Does-IPN-provide-the-billing-address-or-only-the-shipping/td-p/5463